# use of the relative adverb "where" - a case where

Tags: relative-clauses

Can I use a relative adverb "where" when "case" or "instance" is an antecedent?

"case" and "instance" is not a location, but I have seen "a case where" and "an instance where" a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Where**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/where) is not only used for location:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> adverb
> **1 b** : at, in, or to what situation, position, direction, circumstances, or respect
> // *where* does this plan lead
> // *where* am I wrong
>
> conjunction
> **3 b**:  at or in which
> // has reached the size *where* traffic is a problem
> // two fireplaces *where* you can bake bread in the ovens
> — Randall Jarrell
> **4 b** : in a case, situation, or respect in which
> // outstanding *where* endurance is called for
> **5** : THAT
> // I've read *where* they do it that way in some Middle Eastern countries
> — Andy Rooney

There is nothing at all incorrect about using *where* when in any of these constructions. It does not need to be used only for a place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think you can. We usually replace a (preposition + which) structure with "where" for example:

That's the restaurant **in which** we met for the first time.
That's the restaurant **where** we met for the first time.

But is also work when "instance" is used.

There was an instance where it got out of control.

instance = antecedent, it = pronoun

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with this type of construction. "Where" is appropriate when place or location is involved. It may be less clear -- although common in speech and casual writing -- if used as a substitute for "which" or "when."

*That is one of those jobs for which prior experience is required.*

*That is one of those jobs where prior experience is required.*

Some would consider the second case to be less formally correct, because a "job" is not a location. I do note that the third (adverb) definition in Webster's New World Dictionary (Fourth Edition) is:

"in what respect"

And it gives the example "where is he to blame"

So in that sense, where is not absolutely a reference to location.