# Should I use "where" or "that" after "there have been cases"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

For instance：

> Yet there have been cases that/where host cities ended up with heavy debts.

Which one is better in grammar, and why?

Comment: 'That' is incorrect. The metaphorical usage of 'where' meaning 'in which cases/situations' has been covered before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use of the relative adverb "where" - a case where](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494077/use-of-the-relative-adverb-where-a-case-where): 'Can I use a relative adverb "where" when "case" or "instance" is an antecedent?'